# total memory usage of MPI shared memory

Tags: c++, memory, mpi

I am trying to use the MPI share memory feature. I have several SMP nodes, and each of them has four cores. I need an array of size N for each node that should be accessed by all four cores in each node. My plan is to construct a shared window of size N/4 using MPI_Win_allocate_shared, and I expect that memory usage of each node would be N. In the example below, N is 4X10^9 bytes, but the memory usage of each node is not 4GB but 16GB. Am I missing something?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

   int rank_all;
   int rank_sm;
   int size_sm;

   // all communicator
   MPI_Comm comm_sm;
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank_all);

   // shared memory communicator
   MPI_Comm_split_type(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED, 0, MPI_INFO_NULL, &comm_sm);
   MPI_Comm_rank(comm_sm, &rank_sm);
   MPI_Comm_size(comm_sm, &size_sm);

   std::size_t local_window_count(1000000000);

   char* base_ptr;
   MPI_Win win_sm;
   int disp_unit(sizeof(char));
   MPI_Win_allocate_shared(local_window_count * disp_unit, disp_unit, MPI_INFO_NULL, comm_sm, &base_ptr, &win_sm);

   // write
   char buffer;
   if (rank_sm == 0) {
      buffer = 'A';
   }
   else if (rank_sm == 1) {
      buffer = 'C';
   }
   else if (rank_sm == 2) {
      buffer = 'G';
   }
   else {
      buffer = 'T';
   }

   MPI_Win_fence(0, win_sm);

   for (std::size_t it = 0; it < local_window_count; it++) {
      base_ptr[it] = buffer;
   }

   MPI_Win_fence(0, win_sm);

   // read
   long long int index_start(-1 * rank_sm * local_window_count);
   long long int index_end((size_sm - rank_sm) * local_window_count - 1);

   for (long long int it_rel = index_start; it_rel < index_end; it_rel++) {
      buffer = base_ptr[it_rel];

      if (it_rel == index_start) {
         std::cout << rank_sm << " start: " << buffer << std::endl;
      }
      else if (it_rel == (index_end - 1)) {
         std::cout << rank_sm << " end: " << buffer << std::endl;
      }
   }

   MPI_Finalize();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, in the example on page 18, the amount allocate per node is 4 * local_window_count * sizeof(double). If it is true, the amount allocate per node in my code should be 4 * 10^9 * sizeof(char) = 4GB. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question; you're right, of course.  So, more basic questions - how are you checking memory usage, and how are you starting the job?

Comment: I did it using two ways: 1) add "system("sleep 60") to the above code and monitor memory usage using "top" command 2) I have more complex program and I ran it on a cluster using qsub. Qsub usually gives a memory usage report. Page 16 of the slide you mentioned says "Halos (or the data accessed by the neighbors)
must be stored in MPI shared memory windows" and it may be a reason of that.

Comment: I started the job using "mpirun -np 4 <program name>". When I ran it using qsub, "-l nodes=1:ppn=4" was added to the qsub options.